# HTML - Hiding objects based on class

Tags: html

I have a function that hides a div with the corresponding ID based on a radio button change, however, I would like to hide multiple items at once and as ID is unique I am not able to just hide them all. How would I set up a class that I can hide and how would I adjust this code below to make that work?
Any help greatly appreciated

```
function onChangePackage() {
          const nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("baseClass");
          var selectedValue;
          // Get selected radio
          for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].checked) {
              selectedValue = nodes[i].value;
              break;
            }
          }
          // Showing all nodes first
          const nodePostFix = ['A','B','C'];
          nodePostFix.forEach( node => {
            const currentElement = elementsToHide.item(i);
            if (currentElement.hasClass("hidden" + selectedValue)) {
               currentElement.style.display = "none";
            } else {
               currentElement.style.display = "block";
            }
          });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for this purpose together with the [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). So you need just to add the `data-hidden-for` attributes to the required nodes and access them using `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 0):

First give all the elements a base class name `baseClass`. You could just give them a class name like `hidden` and then in your code you could do something like below:

```
const elementsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("baseClass");
for (var i = 0; i < elementsToHide.length; i++) {
   const currentElement = elementsToHide.item(i);
   if (currentElement.hasClass("hidden")) {
      currentElement.style.display = "none";
   } else {
      currentElement.style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

And on the click event of the radio button you could add this class I mentioned above to whichever ones you want to hide:

```
element.classList.add("hidden");
```

or

```
element.classList.remove("hidden");
```

Comment: We can't use a static class name in this case because the different elements must be hidden based on the different options selected. Of course, we can use the dynamic class names but it's better to use data attributes for this purpose.

Comment: so for hiding different things based on the options, how would that work? I'm still quite confused

Comment: @Oleksandr Kovpashko I made changes to the original code if you see above, still can't get it to work, if the code SHOULD work then high chance I have given the classes names wrong, how do i do this properly?

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko why not? Can't he just add the classes by ids?